# How to find who modified/removed the role from the user profile

Tags: security, roles, setup-audit-log

Is there a way to find who modified or removed the role of a particular user in salesforce by other than seeing audit/trial or LastModifiedBy. Because it shows the profile was last modified by one user say 'A'. But how can we be sure that the user 'A' has only removed the role. On the other hand, I could not see any traces in the audit trail that the role has been removed  for the by some one.

Could you please share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should let you to find what you are looking for. Unfortunately we are not allowed to filter by Display where you can find the new of the user whose role get changed, but you can retrieve all records and do a manual search.

```
SELECT
 Display,CreatedBy.Name,CreatedDate
FROM
 SetupAuditTrail
WHERE
 Action LIKE 'changedroleforuser'
LIMIT 100
```